# Click on the link - authorization - redirect to the link

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want my Spring Boot Security to perform the following actions:

1. I follow some link
2. I'm going through authorization
3. Spring redirects me to the same link that I visited in the first paragraph

Any thoughts on how to implement this? I have a rest application.

I found this:

```
public class RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler 
extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

public RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    super();
    setUseReferer(true);
}

}

.formLogin()
.successHandler(new RefererAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
```

But I already have this place, roughly speaking, occupied, and inside I'm doing a manual redirect to /
Can I somehow pull the data from the class above?

My code:

```
    .formLogin()
    .successHandler(new SuccessHandler());

    private class SuccessHandler extends 
    RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements 
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler, LogoutSuccessHandler {

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ....
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
}
```

Comment: It's a default behavior in Spring Security. The initial link is stored in the request context and then used to redirect to after a successful login

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not happen to me

Comment: Please share your security config class

Answer (score 0):

```
        RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
        SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
        if(savedRequest != null && !savedRequest.getRedirectUrl().isEmpty()) {
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
        }
        else {
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).